# What can cause error 500 with PHP form AddRecipient?

Tags: php

I'm working on a contact form with captcha and optional file upload based on:
https://html.form.guide/contact-form/contact-form-attachment/

I cannot get the contactform.php working. This is the php code part:

...

```
<?PHP
/*
    Contact Form from HTML Form Guide
    This program is free software published under the
    terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License.
    See this page for more info:
    http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/contact-form-attachment.html
*/
require_once("./include/fgcontactform.php");
require_once("./include/captcha-creator.php");

$formproc = new FGContactForm();
$captcha = new FGCaptchaCreator('scaptcha');

$formproc->EnableCaptcha($captcha);

//1. Add your email address here.
//You can add more than one receipients.
$formproc->AddRecipient('my@emailaddres.com');          //<<---Put your email address here


//2. For better security get a better string and put it here
$formproc->SetFormRandomKey('XsHVufPpgD9Epwl');

$formproc->AddFileUploadField('photo','jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp',2024);
$formproc->AddFileUploadField('resume','doc,docx,pdf,txt',2024);

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($formproc->ProcessForm())
   {
        $formproc->RedirectToURL("thank-you.php");
   }
}

?>
```

...

When the line "$formproc->AddRecipient('my@emailaddres.com');" is activated my page shows error: HTTP ERROR 500. If I deactivate this line, the page is visisble.

I see many examples with similar code. What can cause this error?

UPDATE:

I just logged into my provider's errorlog as requested:

"FastCGI: server "/var/run/php80-cgi/php-cgi" stderr: PHP message: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$formproc" in /www/nl/contactform.php on line 20"

In all other lines the variable "$formproc" doesn't throw an error, only in the line with the AddRecipients clause. Mu provider seems to be using PHP8.

I don't have a clue what to do next...

Regards, Gerrit

Comment: Take a look at the server logs to find more detail on a 500 error

Comment: Error 500 is a generic 'something wrong on the server' message. Take a look at the server error log to find out what really went wrong.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted here. Is this the actual code running on your server? If not, get a copy of that code and compare it rigorously against this one. I suspect you're missing a semi-colon on line 16.